# PHP formatting number, 35 should be 3500

Tags: php, numbers

I'm working with currencies and there are some items that cost say $35, some that are $35.50, etc.  I'd like to take these numbers and format them to '3500' and if it's 35.50, it should be 3550.

I've tried

```
number_format($data['amount'], 2, '', '')
```

But if it's 35.50 it's 355000.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What value has `$data['amount']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to multiply the number by 100?

Comment: Can't see the trees because of the forest? :)

Comment: @micheal thanks for teaching me a new quote/hipster-phrase today :)

Answer (score 2):

Think of your math lessons:

```
echo $data['amount'] * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), then try this:

```
number_format($data['amount'], 2)
```

with those last two `''` you were replacing the decimal separator with nothing and the thousands separator with nothing, which is something i don't believe you intended to do.

**update**

i see from the comments below that i misread your question.

I tried your code with demo here: http://codepad.org/uNAd84gG

and it seems to be in working order.

Comment: It's not, because it will return 35.00. What the OP wants is 3500.

Comment: I also removed the -1, but still I think multiplying the number by 100 is more elegant than this workaround.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
number_format($amount, 2, ',', '.')
```

You can omit the last 2 to just have it behave by your locale

```
number_format($amount, 2);
```